# Java scoping construct cannot be annotated with type-use

Tags: java, annotations, java-8, checker-framework

I want to annotate a fully qualified class name with `@Nullable`-annotation (from the Java Checker Framework), e.g.:

```
class Demo {
    private transient @Nullable org.apache.lucene.search.Query cached_results;

    // ...
}
```

However this results in the error:

```
scoping construct cannot be annotated with type-use annotation: @checkers.nullness.quals.Nullable
```

How can I annotate fully qualified class names?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Java language specification (draft for version 8)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/se/8/java-se-8-pfd-spec/java-se-8-jls-pfd-diffs.pdf) §8.3 specifies a "UnannClassType" as

> UnannClassType: 
>   Identifier [TypeArguments] 
>   UnannClassOrInterfaceType . {Annotation} Identifier [TypeArguments]

Thus, you need the declaration:

```
private transient org.apache.lucene.search.@Nullable Query cached_results;
```

Or in the augmented java 7 compiler of the checker framework:

```
private transient org.apache.lucene.search./*@Nullable*/ Query cached_results;
```

*NOTE: normal Java compilers ignore `/*@Nullable*/`.*