# Failure using Kotlin Kapt: error: scoping construct cannot be annotated with type-use annotation: @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, error-handling, annotation-processing

I'm using the Vertx Service Gen annotation processor with Kotlin kapt.

Before the annotation processor kick in, my kapt failed with following exception message all over the place:

> error: scoping construct cannot be annotated with type-use annotation:
>   @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

Example of such is as following:

```
e: C:\Users\...\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\main\com\_masked_\objects\User.java:10: error: scoping construct cannot be annotated with type-use annotation: @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    public abstract java.lang.String getUserName();

e: C:\Users\...\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\main\com\_masked_\objects\User.java:13: error: scoping construct cannot be annotated with type-use annotation: @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    public abstract java.lang.String getUrlKey();
                             ^
e: C:\Users\...\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\main\com\_masked_\objects\User.java:16: error: scoping construct cannot be annotated with type-use annotation: @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    public abstract com._.objects.File getAvatar();
                                       ^
...
```

The source code generated by kapt:

```java
public abstract interface User {
    public static final com._.objects.User.Companion Companion = null;

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public abstract java.lang.String getUserName(); // line 10

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public abstract java.lang.String getUrlKey(); // line 13

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public abstract com._.objects.File getAvatar(); // line 16
...
}
```

Its source kotlin file looks like:

```
interface User {

    val userName: String
    val urlKey: String
    val avatar: File
    val signature: String

}
```

Through reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385938/java-scoping-construct-cannot-be-annotated-with-type-use), I kinda understand the situation right now, but how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: This seem to be a kapt bug (not sure), kapt youtrack thread: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35721

Answer (score 2):

This is a kapt bug, issue tracker [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35721)

The workaround kotlin team provide is adding
`implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0")`
to gradle bulid file.